# Current path / SDL library

Tags: c++, c, path, sdl

I'm trying to  get the current executable's file path without the executable name at the end.

I'm doing:

```
uint32_t size = sizeof(path);

if (_NSGetExecutablePath(path, &size) == 0) {


}

else {

    printf("buffer too small; need size %u\n", size);
}



char* program_name = dirname(path); // To remove executable name from the path
```

It works the path output is: **/Users/Me/Desktop/TNT/build/Debug/**

But when i was going to add some gui by using SDL library, the output path was wrong:

**/Users/Me/Desktop/TNT/build/Debug/TNT.app/**

Comment: are you doing C or C++ ? C/C++ is not a language, they are different languages ;)

Comment: ANything that work in C or c++

Comment: C/C++ is not a language... come on, C is a subset of C++ language, isnt it??? ??? ???

Comment: [C is not a subset of C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461331/what-are-the-incompatible-differences-betweeen-c99-and-c11). There is a common subset of C and C++, but it does not align to any particular specification of C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not wrong, it's right.

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_bundle#Mac_OS_X_application_bundles:

> Application bundles are directory hierarchies, with the top-level
>   directory having a name that ends with a .app extension.

TNT.app/ is the working directory (and the top-level directory of the application bundle) on Mac OSX.  You can confirm this if you enter a command shell and `cd` to the directory.

Comment: But if the path ends with TNT.app/ then it can't find my file...

how to fix it?

Comment: I think you want to put your file in the TNT.app directory, generally on Mac that's how applications are bundled with everything under that directory.  If you can't do that you could append "..\" to go one directory backwards.

Comment: Thanks sir, but how can you add "..\" to go one directory back with : printf("executable path is:  \"%s\"\n", program_name);

Comment: if you know the file is one directory back to reference it you could use open("../filename","r") or similar.

Comment: When i made a consol program with same code it works, but why it dosent with gui?

Comment: console app was not built as a .app package, it was probably just a binary file.