# How can I use variable p to declare a new pointer to function using following

Tags: c

I have `p` like:

```
typedef int (*p)();
```

Let's say the function to which I want to declare a pointer is `int foo()`.
I wanna declare a new pointer to function foo using variable p to make use of typedef statement like:

```
typedef int emp[10]; 
emp p;// so now p is an array of size 10 of type int
```

Comment: **What is** your question?

Comment: I wanna declare a new pointer to function foo using variable p to make use of typedef statement. like typedef int emp[10]; emp p;// so now p is an array of size 10 of type int

Comment: Then what you have (`typedef int (*p)();`) is fine. The name `p` will alias this type.

Comment: `p` is the identifer for a pointer type. Just make objects belonging to that type and assign to them: `p myptr1, q; myptr1 = foo; q = quux; myptr1() /* call foo() */; q() /* call quux() */;`

Comment: so tell me the syntax to declare a new pointer to funtion let say 'q' using 'p'

Comment: a link for you: http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html#chapter2

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan thnx a lot.. really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `p` is:

   ```
   typedef int (*p) ();
   ```
2. foo() is:

   ```
   int foo(){
   }
   ```
3. `p` type variable is `f`:

   ```
   p  f = &foo;
   ```
4. how to call using pointer:

   ```
   (*f)();
   ```

Example code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int foo(){
 printf("\n In FOO\n");
 return 4;
}
typedef int(*p)();

int main(){
 p f = &foo;
 int i = (*f)();
 printf("\n i = %d\n", i);
 return 1;
}
```

you can find it is working [**on codepad.**](http://codepad.org/qKUg2h5W)

**note:** you can *simply* assign like `p f = foo;` and  call like `f()` the second form you can find here on  [codepad](http://codepad.org/zU9bKhp6)

Edit: As @Akash commented:

it compiles and runs like:

```
~$ gcc x.c -Wall 
~$ ./a.out 
 In FOO
 i = 4
```

[Here is a project](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf) to help explain the usefulness of function pointers.

Comment: @pmg Yes :) , and also `p  f = foo;` works well ...Just to emphasis on pointer I written in this way.

Comment: @Girijesh I hv tried this already.. It gives following 2 errors
1Must take addrs of a memory allocation
2Declaration Syntax error

Comment: @Aakash you might be doing some error, check the link I proved its working.

Comment: @gaurav just one doubt related to this case... Why doesn't removing "int" in typedef statemnt in my question generates any error

Comment: @Aakash name is Grijesh, Actually I forgot that by mistake earlier, not corrected, Although default return type of a function assumes to be int that what no error at compilation time, Second thing is I updated with one more technique as suggested by Mr. Pmg, find the 2nd codepad link  in answer

Comment: @Girijesh thnx a ton.. n sory for not getting ur name correct

Comment: @Aakash Welcome, and No problem .. check the commented link to your question and **wait** I am giving you a good book on this..

Comment: You don't need the `&` in `p f = &foo;` (you could write `p f = foo;`).

Comment: @Aakash get the book from answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes I have already added a note at bottom in my answer, Mr. Pmg also suggest me that but I wanted to emphasis on pointer/address. Also other answer have the way you are suggesting. My should be different thats the reason... Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
int foo()
{
   // do something
}

typedef int (*p)();

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    int result;

    p funcPtr = foo;    
    result = funcPtr();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wanna declare a new pointer to function foo using variable p to make use of typedef statement.
like typedef int emp[10];
emp p;// so now p is an array of size 10 of type int

Comment: -1: In your code `p` is a type (sorta). You cannot assign to it.

Comment: Now it's ok. I revoked the -1.

Answer (score 0):

With a typedef:

```
typdef int (*FunctionPtr)();

int foo()
{
    return 4; // chosen by fair dice roll, should be random
}

FunctionPtr fptr = foo; // or &foo
```

Without a typedef:

```
int (*fptr)() = foo; // or &foo
```

Comment: That is absolutely fine....
But I want to declare a new pointer to function other than ur (*FunctionPtr)() using (*FunctionPtr)() to make use of typedef statement

Comment: @Aakash I absolutely don't understand your question. What's not "new enough" in my approach? Try rephrasing your requirement using a better English, I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: I want to do following but it gives error
typedef int (*p)();
int foo()
{}
int main()
{    int c;
    p q;
    q=fun()
   c=(*q)();
    return 0;
}

Comment: @Aakash 1. Write that in your question, 2. format it. Then I can be bothered reading it.

Comment: look at gaurav chauhan's answer. that's what i wanted

Comment: @Aakash That's no different from mine.

Answer (score 0):

From this post: [convert C function array to c++ functions pointer array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11591165/convert-c-function-array-to-c-functions-pointer-array)

```
 #include <stdio.h>

void f1() {printf("helo\n");}
void f2() {printf("world\n");}

typedef struct func
{
    void (*f)();
}func;

int main()
{
    func a[] = {{f1}, {f2}};
    a[0].f();
    return 0;
}
```