# Differences between certain standards of C and C++

Tags: c++, c, c++11, c++03, c11

Where can i see all differences between C++11 and C99?

I think that C++98 and C++03 based on C89 / C90. Is there any differences between them? And what about C++11 and C99? Some features from C99 were added to C++11, but others not (like compound literals, VLAs, etc). Can i see complete list of this changes or not?

Comment: A good reference on the changes between the C++03 and C++11 standards is actually the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11).

Comment: You are asking whether there are any differences between C and C++!?  Yes of course there are; they are different languages!  I am not sure how your question as it stands can be answered in any meaningful way.

Comment: it is similar to this question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461331/what-are-the-incompatible-differences-betweeen-c99-and-c11

Comment: I don't want to get differences between different C++ or C standards. And yes, i know that C and C++ are different languages, but some features from C were added to C++.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard has Appendix C, which lists differences between C and C++. It was updated for C++11, which does, indeed, incorporate much of C99 by reference. The appendix isn't complete; it hits the major differences.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this interview will be useful for your purpose:

[The C Family of Languages: Interview with Dennis Ritchie, Bjarne Stroustrup, and James Gosling](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/c_family_interview.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The statement `I think that C++98 and C++03 based on C89 / C90.` is wrong. Stroustrup created C++ in mid 80's. Since then these 2 lines diverged. They were influencing one another. But not more than that. 2 different teams were developing these 2 standards. There were no obligations between them.